# WS_EX_COMPOSITED and scrollbar not drawing whilst being dragged

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has many  custom controls on that had a terrible flicker, I found the following code (here on stackoverflow whilst searching for a solution, [How to fix the flickering in User controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612487/how-to-fix-the-flickering-in-user-controls)
or [Winforms Double Buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718380/winforms-double-buffering) posted by Hans Passant) which fixed the flicker

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
        return cp;
    }
}
```

However, now if I click the position bar on the scrollbar, the position bar stays fixed, until I let go of the mouse button.

Is there a way to have the scroll position bar update whilst being dragged and not have flicker on the controls?

Many thanks

Comment: Attribution is required here.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/is-it-legal-to-copy-stack-overflow-questions-and-answers

Comment: Have edited the question to say I found the above code here, actually I believe it was one of your posts.

<edit2>
Have found and added the URLs and it was in fact you, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

[smooth scrolling .net forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424482/smooth-scrolling-net-forms)

Answer found here, all thanks to CharlesW

```
private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

protected override void WndProc (ref Message m)
{
    if ((m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
    && (((int)m.WParam & 0xFFFF) == 5))
    {
        // Change SB_THUMBTRACK to SB_THUMBPOSITION
        m.WParam = (IntPtr)(((int)m.WParam & ~0xFFFF) | 4);
    }
base.WndProc (ref m);
}
```