# Smooth drawing or painting of child controls in Panel while scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, smooth-scrolling

While using Panel control in TabPage of Tab control, I have quite a few child controls like RichTextBox, Buttons, Labels etc.

Problem is when I scroll in the Panel, there is a flickering inside. The child controls are not being shown/drown/painted smoothly like they are already there.

Looking for something that could make this scrolling smooth and remove the flickering effect.
Any suggestions would help a lot. I tried a several other methods like DoubleBuffered, but didn't really work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I solved the problem with combination of different other suggestions, below is the code that removed flickering for me, essentially making it DoubleBuffered using Win API.

References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9811326/1584507) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89125/1584507).

```
public partial class SmoothScrollPanel : UserControl
{
    public SmoothScrollPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
        && (((int)m.WParam & 0xFFFF) == 5))
        {
            // Change SB_THUMBTRACK to SB_THUMBPOSITION
            m.WParam = (IntPtr)(((int)m.WParam & ~0xFFFF) | 4);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious: Do you know what the fiddlin with the Scrolling does and do you see a difference compared to simply setting DoubleBuffered  to true in a sub-classed Panel?

Comment: @TaW: Hummm, I really don't know what makes it different when settings this.DoubleBuffered = true; and through Win API. Seems to have worked for me. I can't see the flickering anymore. 
But if I simply use this.DoubleBuffered = true; that wouldn't work, I get flickering.
BTW, my bad, I didn't use this.DoubleBuffered = true; in my solution.
Updating answer now. It works without that just using Win API, flickering is gone.